# Gradle Exec task - params with spaces aren't surrounded using quotes

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I've got problem with spaces in gradle exec task - params with spaces aren't surrounded using quotes.

For example lets create this simple project (created on windows)

*C:\dir with spaces\build.gradle* // it's very important to put project into directory which path contains spaces

```
task execTest(type: Exec) {
    def runFromGradle = new File(projectDir, 'runFromGradle.bat').getAbsolutePath()
    commandLine 'cmd', '/C', runFromGradle, projectDir.absolutePath
    // commandLine 'cmd', '/C', '"'+runFromGradle+'"', '"'+projectDir.absolutePath+'"' // it also doesn't work
}
```

*C:\dir with spaces\build.gradle\runFromGradle.bat*

```
dir "%1"
```

After I run this project using `gradle execTest`, cmd returns this error `'C:\dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. I've tried to use ant.exec and put paths in quotes but without success. Project works fine if I'll change first parameter (runFromGradle) from absolute path to relative but I don't want to do it in this way.

In our real project we use command line with numbers of command line parameters that contains spaces.

I use gradle 1.6.

Comment: What happens if you surround the affected argument(s) with spaces yourself? I wouldn't expect it to be necessary (or even correct) though, as Gradle/Java should pass the arguments one by one to the process.

Comment: Instead of `new File(projectDir, 'runFromGradle.bat').getAbsolutePath()` you can just use `file('runFromGradle.bat').` Also, you can omit the occurrences of `.absolutePath`.

Comment: Pieter, I tried to surround arguments using quotes but without success. BTW, as you wrote, java/groovie/gradle should do this. Thank you for your second guidance, I do it in this way to show the problem with spaces.

Comment: Pieter, have you tried to run this example on your computer? Does it work?

Comment: I'm not on Windows. Gradle effectively passes `commandLine` through to `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`, and it's not clear to me what else it could or should do. This may be more a matter of understanding how `cmd` works, rather than how Gradle works. I'd try to concatenate `runFromGradle` and `projectDir`, with and without quotes. Another attempt is to use `canonicalPath` instead of `absolutePath`. Also I'd consult the documentation for `cmd` and play with `cmd /C` on the command prompt.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html looks like a good treatment (see examples at the very end). In the case that both the program path and the arguments may contain spaces, I'm not sure how it translates to `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` though. One thing I'd try is to use double quotes just for `runFromGradle`. Otherwise I'd try to convert the paths into a form without spaces (there is a legacy syntax that Windows supports). Maybe `canonicalPath` will do just that.

Comment: Yet another idea is to set `execTest.workingDir` to `projectDir` and then use relative paths.

Comment: I have encountered a similar problem when trying to execute this command from Gradle: bin/rake spec RAILS_ENV=test SPEC_OPTS='--fail-fast -e"Check Administrator privileges"'. While this command works perfectly fine when executed from the command line, it seems it's not possible to do it with Gradle's Exec task, as whitespaces get encoded.